# How to interact with discord using powershell commands

Tags: powershell, discord

I need to write a Discord bot using PowerShell. The rules are as follows:

```
1. The bot must be able to read messages with the prefix 'psdo '
2. The bot must be able to get the reactions of messages
3. The bot must be able to send messages
4. The bot must be able to edit messages
```

However, there is no way to do so with webhooks as I know. I have a second discord account and could create an application but I need an entrypoint; some method to do these things. I need to do this strictly in powershell. Is there a way to accomplish all of the rules above? I only need the code to do these, and then I can handle the rest for myself.
PS - I have a server where I am the owner, so I can do anything in the server I'm making.

Comment: There are plenty of guides and examples for writing Discord bots in other languages; perhaps you could look at those and see what they have to say? It is quite likely that translating from a language such as python might be a fruitful approach.

Comment: I have, but all of them have either been in other programming languages or about webhooks. i already know how to use webhooks, I want to be able to interact with a proper bot.